# archfs: backup does mount, but files are not accessible

Tags: rdiff-backup

`archfs` is a tool that lets one mount a rdiff-backup as a drive, and then browse the contents of the backup as if they were snapshots (think if BackInTime or Rsnapshot).

rdiff-backup is a great tool made even greater by archfs. If it would only work...

**What I did**:

1. create a folder on my desktop, called "backup"
2. attach my USB drive containing the rdiff backup,
3. then: `archfs '/home/david/Desktop/backup' '/media/david/BACKUP/home'`

`/home/david/Desktop/backup` contains these folders, `david` and `rdiff-backup-data`. I backup my home directory there.)

When I click on the backup folder to open it, an error occurs:

```
"Sorry, could not display all the contents of “backup”: Transport endpoint is not connected"
```

- What should I do? --David

Comment: I used "sudo chown -R david:david" on my backup disk, before invoking archfs. Now it seems to work...